# TypeError: object() takes no parameters python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newer for python I get a error  like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/learn/ClassAttributes/MutabilityofClassAttributes.py", line 7, in <module>
    s1 = Service(['a', 'b'])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

the code is there thanks!

```
 class Service(object):
     data = []

     def __int__(self, other_data):
         self.other_data = other_data

 s1 = Service(['a', 'b'])
 s2 = Service(['c', 'd'])
```

Comment: Did you make a typo in the `__init__()` method definition? Also why do you use `self.other_data` when there is only `data` in the instance field?

Comment: Oh,I'am so careless I'am learning  a code like this

Comment: class Person(object):
              all_names = []

              def __init__(self, name):
                     elf.name = name
                      Person.all_names.append(name)

           joe = Person('Joe')
           bob = Person('Bob')
           print Person.all_names
           ## ['Joe', 'Bob']

Comment: the code like this

Comment: like a public variable  can  call it in the  __init__() method